# Apple Watch Series 3 ski tracking

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

Apple Watch Series 3 was announced to have **ski** tracking possibility. But I cannot find any information on the web if it already possible. Can anyone that has Apple Watch confirm, that you can now track skiing activity, and if so, what exactly can you track? Does it offer similar capabilities as **Slopes** or **Trace** apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's still no ski tracking capabilities in any of the Apple Watch series.

But, all the data inputs needed are there. Barometer, motion tracking, heart rate tracking, location via GPS and cell tower trilateration, etc...

After the initial announcement, Apple referenced that this feature would be available toward the end of 2017, probably before winter.

The HomePod IPSW leak a few months ago provided some indication that Apple would add this feature to Workouts.  [This screen grab](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/08/01/skiing-workout-apple-watch/) shows there's references to skiing workouts already built into the firmware.
[image]

For now, you can use the myriad of different ski tracking apps out there.

Comment: Yes - this is my read. Apple was announcing that the health app will have a place for this to be exposed just like it added stairs climbed, resting heart rate, walking heart rate, exercise heart rate after they added the basic heart rate to health app.